# Confusion between dual of continuous functions and borel functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let
 $$C(X) = \{\text{ Continuous complex functions on } X\}$$ 
$$B(X) = \{ \text{Bounded complex Borel-measurable functions on X}\}$$
 both equipped with the sup-norm, and therefore Banach spaces.

We have that $C(X)^*=M(X)$ is the set of complex Radon measures, while $B(X)^* = \operatorname{ba}(X)$ are the bounded, [finitely additive measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space).

Each element $T$ of $\operatorname{ba}(X)$ is continuous when restricted to $C(X)\subset B(X)$. Thus, by the Riesz representation theorem, there is a countably additive Radon measure on $C(X)$ corresponding to $T$. However, all the elements of $M(X)$ are countably additive, while those in $B(X)$ need not be!

I am wondering where I am going wrong as I get this contradictory conclusion.

Thank you.

Comment: By the Hahn-Banach theorem on $B(X)$, each element of $M(X)$ extends to $B(X)$  Explain please?

Comment: $C(X)$ is a closed subspace of $B(X)$ under the sup norm - each bounded linear functional on $C(X)$ must extend to a bounded linear functional on $B(X)$. Alternatively, every countably additive bounded measure is also finitely additive bounded.

Comment: The extension will be far from unique.

Comment: It's the other direction that is giving me the problem (Edited question for clarity) - is it that the measure guaranteed by the Riesz representation theorem for $C(X)$ need not be the same as the measure we originally started out with? (As $M(X)$ is a quotient of $B(X)$)

Comment: You mean $T$ on the dual of $B(X)$?

Comment: oops $M(X)$ is a quotient of $ba(X)$ I mean.

Comment: I am trying to take a limit of a sequence $g_n\to g$ pointwise, $\{g_n\}\subset C(G)$, with respect to an element $T\in  ba(G)$ i.e $\lim_n T(g_n)$. I am confused if I can use DCT here - since $T$ will be countably additive as a measure corresponding to $C(X)^*$. However, the two dualities are confusing me.

Comment: Excuse the ignorance, but what does "the restriction of $T$ to $C(X)$" even mean? If $T\in B(X)\setminus C(X),$ how are you going to "restrict" it? Or maybe I am missing the point totally!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma and Matematleta Sorry about the confusion, I see the error now, I meant $T\in ba(X)$.

Comment: How do you get a contradiction here? This just means that for any bounded, finitely additive measure $\nu$, there is some bounded countably additive measure $\mu$ such that $\int_X f d\nu = \int_X f d\mu$ for all $f \in C(X)$. And multiple $\nu$ could have the same restriction $\mu$.